# How to validate the cloned textefields by using jquery validation?

Tags: jsp, jquery-validate, jquery-clone

Hi could anyone please explain me about how to validate the cloned text fields by using jquery validate plugin and additional method plugin.My HTML code is like this.Here I have one addnew button when i click on that I will clone the same text fields to the bellow.

**JSP**

```
 <input type="hidden" id="experiencelength" name="experiencelength" value=""/>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td> <input type="text" id="previouscompanyname" name="previouscompanyname" maxlength="200" class="input-large" style="height:27px; " value="${param.previouscompanyname}"/>          
                                        <p id="previouscompanyname" style="color: red"/>
                                        <html:errors property="previouscompanyname"/></td>
                                    <td> <input type="text" id="jobtitle" name="jobtitle" maxlength="200" class="input-large" style="height:27px; " value="${param.jobtitle}"/>          
                                        <p id="jobtitle" style="color: red"/>
                                        <html:errors property="jobtitle"/></td>
                                    <td> <input type="text"  class="input-large datepicker" style="height:27px;" readonly="true" id="jobfromdate" name="jobfromdate"  value="${param.dateofjoining}"/>
                                        <html:errors property="jobfromdate"/></td>
                                    <td>  <input type="text"  class="input-large datepicker" style="height:27px;" readonly="true" id="jobtodate" name="jobtodate"  value="${param.dateofjoining}"/>
                                        <html:errors property="jobtodate"/></td><td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="workexperience">Add New</button>
```

**Cloning Script**

```
 $("#workexperience").click(function() {
//        var jobfromdate = 0;
        var date = '<td><input type="text" class="input-large datepicker" style="height:27px;" readonly="true" id="jobtodate1' + j + '" name="jobtodate1"/></td>';
        var date1 = '<td><input type="text" class="input-large datepicker" style="height:27px;" readonly="true" id="jobfromdate' + k + '" name="jobfromdate"/></td>';
        var remve = '<td><button type="button"  class="removeworkexperience" class="btn btn-info" >x</button></td>';
        $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').clone(true).insertAfter($(this).closest('tr').prev('tr')).find('td:last-child').remove().find('td:last-child').remove();
        $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('td:last-child').remove();
        $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('td:last-child').remove();
        $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').append(date).append(date1).append(remve);
        $('#jobtodate1' + j).datepicker();
        $('#jobfromdate' + k).datepicker();
        ++k;
        ++j;
        document.getElementById("experiencelength").value = j;
    });
```

**Vaidation**

```
 $('#employee_table').validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true,
                letterswithbasicpunc: true
            },
            lastname: {
                minlength: 1,
                required: true,
                letterswithbasicpunc: true
            },
            generateemployeeID: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            sourceofhire: {
                required: true
            },
            designation: {
                letterswithbasicpunc: true
            },
            otheremail: {
                email: true,
                minlength: 10

            },
            previouscompanyname:{
                 required: true
            },
            agree: "required"

        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(element) {
            element
                    .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                    .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot validate a "cloned" field since it will contain a duplicate `name`.  Every field considered for validation must contain a *unique* `name` attribute, as that's the way this plugin keeps track of validation.

So you'll need to rework your code to create a unique `name` similar to how you're creating a unique `id`.  You'll also need to declare the rules similar to how you're initializing the `.datepicker()` plugin.

Use the plugin's `.rules()` method....

```
$('input[name="myNewUniqueName"]').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    minlength: 1
});
```